# Simulation of an Electric Shock Box

Tags: circuit-analysis, transformer, simulation, npn, shock

This is the continuity of this: [Understanding Electric Shock Box Circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/459685/understanding-electric-shock-box-circuit/459689?noredirect=1#comment1157300_459689)

I really don't understand what is going on, so I was hoping that simulating the circuit in Proteus might help
[image]

What parameters should I pick for the transformer?
[image]

For example, in Primary Magnetic Inductance do I need to add the inductance of the Primary Extremes, without counting the center-tap, right? I don't know what to select in Turns Ratio (Np/Ns), neither in leakage inductance, neither in trace inductance, neither in Losses .. Could you help me?

These are the values that I have gathered about the transformer:

Primary

- Red_1-Red_2 = 760 mH / 6.8 Ohms
- Red_1-White = 150 mH / 3.8 Ohms
- Red_2-White = 148 mH / 3.2 Ohms

Secondary

- Black_1-Black_2 = 33.5 H / 514.6 Ohms

Unfortunately, when I try to run the simulation with the parameters previous displayed, Proteus shows an error:
[image]

I was also thinking, what would be the equivalent circuit of a human body? Currently in the simulation I am using a 250 Ohm resistor, but as I long as I understand the human body also behaves as a capacitor
[image]

and I have seen models that add an inductance component too .. So, does any one know what would be an equivalent circuit? What values of resistance and capacitance should I pick?